# Copy tooltip content in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tooltip

While editing code in Visual Studio, it will sometimes underline something I wrote, and when I hover over it, display a tooltip saying something like `blah blah is obselete, please use this instead. See [some MSDN link]`. However, when I try to move the mouse over the tooltip so I can click on the link or copy it to the clipboard, the tooltip disappears, since it's set to only appear when I hover over offending the code, not over the tooltip.

Does anyone know a way to get at the tooltip contents? And if not... I'm not a UI designer but shouldn't it be obvious to anyone designing such a feature that people need a way to get to the link other than typing it into the browser??

Comment: not sure if there is a better way, but if you build your project the same error message will appear on output window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try go to definition of method, open as metadata view and you'll see the obselete attribute above the method with the text description